# What is the official Schedule of Basic Child-Support Obligations for Alabama?

Tags: divorce, alabama

I've looked online for a table of what child support would be in Alabama.  All I can find is this: [Schedule of Basic Child-Support Obligations for the State of Alabama](http://www.alacourt.gov/docs/Alabama%20updated%20schedule%202008.1.pdf). Is there a more recent version than 2007?

Comment: Why are you asking here? Try http://www.alacourt.gov/Contact.aspx

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I've emailed them.  If they respond, I will post as an answer

Comment: @BlueDogRanch In case you are wondering, I'm still waiting on that response :)